# Tortoise SVN update a branch anfter merging to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, branch, tortoisesvn

Goodmorning,

Two devs, for example Bill and Max, are using tortoise SVN and they have created a trunk for a project (called "prj-trunk"); after that, they made two branch (with branch/tag option of tortise), one for each dev (called "prj-branch-max" and "prj-branch-bill").
In his branch Max made same modification and in the other Bill modify other file.
Now is time to merge in the trunk, so one dev use "merge" option of tortoise for put his code in trunk, and after that, other dev "merge" his file to trunk.
So the scenario now is that: Prj-Trunk with all modification, prj-merge-max only with max's modifications and prj-merge-bill with only bill's modification.
So what is the best way to update the two merge with all modification?
The first think I try is, starting with updated prj-trunk, make a merge with "merge" option pointing to "prj-branch-max" but tortoise SVN not find any modification (so the file updated from bill and merged in trunk, aren't recognized as new). I also try to make another branch with "branch/tag" option pointing to "prj-branch-max" but tortoise SVN return error (it say "already exist").
So what is correct way to do?
Thanks you

Resuming:

| Time | prj-trunk | branch-max | branch-bill |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t0 | creation with file A.c, B.c, etc.. | not exist | not exist |
| t1 | no modification | branch from trunk | branch from trunk |
| t2 | no modification | fila A.c modified | file B.c modified |
| t3 | merge from Max (A.c updated, B.c old) | no modification | no modification |
| t4 | merge from Bill (both file are updated) | no modification | no modification |
| t5 | [no modification] | try to merge from trunk BUT not found any modification, so merge aborted by TortoiseSVN | [as for Max] |
| t6 | [no modification] | try to branch (off curse, is not the right procedure, but it is the last try!) from trunk BUT already exist, so branch aborted by TortoiseSVN | as for Max |
| t7 | [no modification] | delete folder in local and commit the delete in server; after that brench another time from trunk (that is up-to-date with all modification)... this is the wrong way, but i didn't discover any other solution | as for Max |

Ok please someone can tell me how to do the correct procedure starting from time #4 for update bill and max's brench??

Comment: "so the file updated from bill anche merged in trunk, aren't recognized as new" - this should not happen. Did you update the working copy before? Does the file actually contain the modification made by Bill?

Comment: @Friedrich thanks for your answer. Yes all updated (otherwise Tortoise return error...) I'm at your same opinion: this should not happen, and so it was very strange when I saw that merge from trunk to max-branch can't be completed. Sure all file A.c and B.c contain modifications...

Comment: Just to make it clear: creating a branch that already exists is the **wrong** approach. I think we already agree on that but I wanted to write it explicitly.

Comment: Hi, you are absolutly right, I edit the main post and explain. This is only the last test before delete all folder and restart again all from prj-trunk (merged version)

Comment: In your "t3", that should be "merge from Max", right? You might try to reproduce your problem using the CLI. It's much easier to post commands as text than to describe what you click in a GUI. One last thought: did you `switch` your working copy? Creating a branch alone does not change your working copy, you also need to switch to the new branch.

Comment: hi, my fault, I edited now. Correct is "merge" not "brench" on t3.
Maybe you find the mistake: i NEVER switch.
We don't have scope of folder, so evreyone can see (and modify....) the folder and file of other brench...
When I make a brench I download all repository and work in the correct brench, and never in trunk (unless for merge!) so we never switch anything and, to tell you the true, I didn't know very well this command and what is used for... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a branch in Subversion, it is created in the repository. The working copy is unaffected and needs to be *switched* to the newly created branch in order to change it.

Using the command line client and the conventional trunk-branches layout, one would issue the following commands; in TortoiseSVN, one would use the analogous actions:

```bash
touch A.c B.c
svn add A.c B.c
svn commit -m"Initial, empty files"
svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/max -m"Create branch for Max"
svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/bill -m"Create branch for Bill"

# At this point, working copy is still on trunk
svn switch ^/branches/max
vi A.c # make changes, etc.
svn commit -m"Max' changes to A"

svn switch ^/branches/bill
vi B.c # make changes, etc.
svn commit -m"Bill's changes to B"

# Now let's bring it together in trunk
svn switch ^/trunk
svn merge ^/branches/max .
# Resolve conflicts, if any (there shouldn't be any)
svn commit -m"Merge Max' changes"
svn merge ^/branches/bill .
# Resolve conflicts, if any (there shouldn't be any)
svn commit -m"Merge Bill's changes"

# Now let's merge those changes to Max' branch
svn switch ^/branches/max
svn merge ^/trunk .
# Resolve conflicts, if any (there shouldn't be any)
svn commit -m"Merge from trunk"

# Same for Bill
```

For more information on branching and merging, refer to the canonical resource on Subversion, the [Red Bean Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).

Comment: Hi Friedrich. thanks before all for your anser, I'll read Read-Bean-Book sooner.  What I can't figure out is what is the difference between your solution (point working copy to brench) or, like a made before, download from SVN the brench (via "SVN Update" command creating on my PC the extra folder of brench) and work on it. What I understand is the "change pointer" is only for have in my pc the folder with same name but it is referred to the brench instead the trunk, but for me isn't a problem have both folder (trunk and my brench) simultaneous. thank yuo

Comment: Thank you. If my answer solves your problem (and only then!), please accept it using the V-shaped button next to it. You are however free to wait for better answers. If you have a follow-up question, post another one on this site. Regarding directory layout, I described the most common choice. It has the benefit that local paths are stable even if you switch branches. YMMV.

Comment: up arrow and V-shaped button... Already done :-)
Thanks you for your explanation

Answer (score -1):

Each user can add files first then commit to the main branch.

Max changed file1 and Bill file2:
Max needs to do : svn add main-repo (if new file for ex) then commit svn ci file1
Same thing for Bill

Then you just need to update your repo so to have the last updates files.

As far as Bill and Max aren't working on the same file, file0 let's say, you won't have problem.

But if they work on the same file, svn can't handle this case, it will only take the last updated file version.

So you need to first update

Comment: "But if they work on the same file, svn can't handle this case, it will only take the last updated file version." - this is plain wrong. Subversion will refuse to commit if there are newer changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Let me explain better:  Max and Bill modified only different file, never modify the same file!

Comment: @Friedrich What's wrong with that part ? It's just impossible to modify the same file in svn to be concrete. Svn creates locks if a user is modifying a file so that anyone else can do so. Technically they can't work on the same file. But they do it meaning working on the same copy of same file, svn will take the change of the last one who has locked the file and commiitted. Subversion will commit if there are newer changes but only for the user who has the locked. Better if a new user want to change the message saying that the file is locked will appear !

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong again. In Subversion, the term *lock* has a specific meaning and no, editing a file won't lock it. There also won't be a message saying so (unless the file was locked for unrelated reasons). Subversion will also refuse commits from the same user if their working copy is out of date. You are more than welcome to [edit] and improve your answer. I would be happy to upvote a correct and helpful answer.

Comment: Lol. I may guess that you are a great contributor here with a certain background but... have you ever read something about svn or work with svn ? -Délirant ! What do you think about these articles : 1) https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html 2) https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html#:~:text=In%20the%20Subversion%20repository%2C%20a,known%20as%20the%20lock%20token. ?? I invite you to revise things about svn. Have a nice day.  @holyhope hope this can help, I suggest you to read the official documentation.